# Jekyll / gem: Unresolved specs

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I am using Jekyll, I have two independent repositories, and I think I updated one recently. Everything was working fine last time I rendered my blog. Now just this:

```
$ jekyll serve --watch
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      redcarpet (~> 3.1)
      jekyll-watch (~> 1.1)
      classifier-reborn (~> 2.0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.2/bin/jekyll:21:in `block in <top (required)>': cannot load such file -- jekyll/version (LoadError)
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary.rb:18:in `program'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.2/bin/jekyll:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

What the heck is going on? It seems Jekyll or Gem killed itself. How can I fix this?

How can I prevent that Jekyll or Ruby is messing around with the global install (I think that's what's happening-the two blogs are not independent of each other)? Can I ensure that each Jekyll directory is isolated from another, like in any descent programming language / build system?

---

**Edit**. I randomly ran `sudo gem cleanup && bundle install`. This seems to have *uninstalled* (!?!) all the gems, then re-installed them. Now I get a different error:

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      listen (~> 2.7)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
```

Am I right to assume that gem/bundle has no idea what a transitive dependency is?

```
$ bundle show listen
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/listen-2.7.11
```

So there *is* listen. So why does Jekyll complain?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems that you're not the only one to have this kind of problem. [See issue here.](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3084)

I managed to bypass this problem in two ways.

On Jekyll 2.5.x, removing `Gemfile` simply make the error disappear.

If Gemfile is needed, a `bundle exec jekyll serve` is ok.

Comment: Great! I changed `jekyll serve` for `bundle exec jekyll serve`. It has always worked without `bundle exec` before, so I don't know what changed, but prefixing makes it work.

Comment: Had this problem in 2018, really weird. Deleting the Gemfile seems to have fixed it.