# jekyll 3.0.1 | Error: undefined method `map!' for nil:NilClass

Tags: jekyll

I wanted to do an update to a jekyll site - but when trying out "jekyll serve" I now get:

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      jekyll-watch (~> 1.1)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Configuration file: /home/ligi/git/espass.github.io/_config.yml
jekyll 3.0.1 | Error:  undefined method `map!' for nil:NilClass
```

also fails with bundle exec jekyll serve

```
➜  espass.github.io git:(master) ✗ bundle exec jekyll serve 
Configuration file: /home/ligi/git/espass.github.io/_config.yml
jekyll 3.0.1 | Error:  undefined method `map!' for nil:NilClass
```

Anyone knows how to trace down this error? Don't find anything about it in the internet and am kinda stuck here

Edit:

```
➜  espass.github.io git:(master) ✗ bundle exec jekyll serve --trace
Configuration file: /home/ligi/git/espass.github.io/_config.yml
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/configuration.rb:246:in `block in backwards_compatibilize': undefined method `map!' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/configuration.rb:238:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/configuration.rb:238:in `backwards_compatibilize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/configuration.rb:189:in `read_config_files'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll.rb:101:in `configuration'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/command.rb:42:in `configuration_from_options'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:29:in `process'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/bin/jekyll:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jekyll / gem: Unresolved specs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27196896/jekyll-gem-unresolved-specs)

Comment: @DavidJacquel It is not a dup - my problem is not the missing dep but the nilpointer

Comment: You can try to reinstall your gems.

Comment: getting the same error after "sudo gem cleanup && bundle install"

Comment: Any repository url available ?

Comment: https://github.com/esPass/espass.github.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited answer** : Watching your trace, we can see that you have a collision between

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/
```

and

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/
```

Personnaly, I go with [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) also in order to avoid such situation.

**old answer** :

If you use `bundler`, you must start Jekyll with `bundle exec jekyll serve`.

I've just tested it on your repository, it's works well.

Comment: I get the same then: 
> bundle exec jekyll serve 
Configuration file: /home/ligi/git/espass.github.io/_config.yml
jekyll 3.0.1 | Error:  undefined method `map!' for nil:NilClass

Comment: `bundle exec jekyll serve --trace` ?

Comment: added the trace to my question

Comment: Gem are colliding. Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for the input - unfortunately I get the same with rbenv: https://gist.github.com/ligi/4fd9b76397e3d30da9eb4ef4573572dc I am not using ruby often ( only for jekyll currently ) so it might be something I miss there - upvoted but I cannot yet accept as I cannot verify

Comment: I got it - your hint was right - I just uninstalled ruby and now it is working again - thanks - accepted answer